# Usage limit on Bing geocoding vs Google geocoding?

Tags: geocoding, bing

I know that the google geocoding api has a 2,500 hits a day limit before it'll start returning REQUEST_DENIED. How many does the bing one take? I heard that it's unlimited but I had trouble confirming that.

Comment: http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/developer/archive/2012/04/12/bing-dev-update.aspx

Comment: Yeah but that's only for the search right? I didn't see any mention of geocoding

Comment: not sure  i think it will be for all their API usage

Comment: here is an old article from 2008 that says that the limit is 10k : http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2008/07/28/overcoming-pushpin-limitations-in-mappoint-2009.aspx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about API limits which can change any time

Answer (score 8):

Just came across this question. It's a bit old but still relevant. For Bing Maps there are two different ways to geocode address. The first is with batch geocoding which has the limits outlined  by alfski.

The second option is the REST geocoding service which allows you to geocode one address at a time. The free transactions for the Bing Maps services varies depending on use case. For Windows/Windows Phone/WPF apps you can make up to 50,000 transactions a day under the free terms of use. For other platforms such as iOS, Android and Web apps there is 125,000 transactions allowed per year for free. You can find more details on this here: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/create-a-bing-maps-key.aspx

Comment: Update: Maximum 10,000 cumulative billable transactions in any 30-day period.(Trail Key)

Comment: That's for business apps under trial. Unless the app in an internal, asset tracking app were there is no basic key option, or share the code with another company, I always recommend creating a basic key as that make things easier and saves headaches as there is a limit to the number of keys that can be created in an account.

Answer (score 4):

The Microsoft Bing Maps terms & conditions are at http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html

The T&C's will change so please check the link.

As of January 2013 under the General Terms of Use, the Bing geocoding limits are:

"a total of 5 batch geocoding or file uploads with a maximum of 50 records each, using the Bing Spatial Data Services API, within any 24 hour period."

However if you have a Bings Map Agreement:

"...a total of 24 batch geocoding or file uploads with a maximum of 200,000 records each, using the Bing Spatial Data Services API, within any 24 hour period.

Comment: In April, terms have changed and a limitation can now be seen regarding non-billable transaction as well as lower number of batch geocoding by day.

Answer (score 1):

1) Google Maps API recently changed their prices:

Standard plan:

```
2,500 requests per day free.
After that is $0.50 per 1000 requests.
```

Premium plan:

```
Pay $10,000/year.
Get 100,000 requests per day "for free".
Above that - 500,000 requests per year are "free".
Above that - buy next package.
```

However "Web service APIs and the JavaScript API require the Premium Plan."
My understanding is that formally you must use Premium Plan ($10000/year) if you are calling geocoding from your server (not mobile phone).

More details here: http://dennisgorelik.livejournal.com/112993.html

2) Bing Maps API does not publish their prices.

Comment: Always add official source urls

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Licensing tool to find out how much they'll charge you

http://www.microsoft.com/maps/Licensing/licensing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

By the way you can also try Yandex Geocoding API which is for free for up to 25.000 Requests per day per Website/Mobile App:

http://api.yandex.com/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params.xml

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer as of Feb 2022**

Google Maps offers a $200 monthly [credit](https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/), which is equivalent to 40,000 free geocodes per month.

Bing Maps allows you to sign up for a "basic key" for development purposes which gives you 125,000 free geocodes per calendar year. Their licensing page is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/licensing/licensing-options/).