# Get many geo maps for addresses

Tags: api, dictionary, gps

How can I get maps for addresses without requests limits ? Google provide only 2500 requests per day. First of all, I want to use free services. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a similar question [Usage limit on Bing geocoding vs Google geocoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213431/usage-limit-on-bing-geocoding-vs-google-geocoding).

Google will start denying your request at around 2500. Bing has a much higher daily limit (used to be 30k - i think it's up to 50k now).

There are a number of free geo-coding services. I recommend staggering your requests to use multiple services if you need a large number of addresses coded daily. Here's a list of 54 providers: http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/geocoding.

Comment: You have to be careful doing this as mixing geocode results from different providers is usually against the terms of use of each data provider.

Answer (score 1):

You left a ton of info out... What the heck is maps for addresses? Do you mean map tiles? Or are you talking about geocoding? Like getting addresses for maps.

Is it a website making the calls or mobile? Where are you exicuting the code from?

If you are talking about gps geocoding (getting an adress from a GPS cord) then there are tricks you can use to get around those limits. If it's based on a key then its a 2500 limit for the key. However, there are apis you can use that are based on calling IP (google is one) If you make the client make the call then unless your client is making 2500 calls your good to go.

You will notice here that the geocoding call doesn't require an api key. So the usagelimit is going to be based on calling IP

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests