# usage limits of google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to use the google-maps-api v3 for the following tasks:

1. address-autocomplete in search field
2. calculate distance from search input to search results (locations in my own database)
3. show the locations (with small distance) on a map

I can show up to 25000 maps per day for free. But what is with the features in task (1) and (2)? Are they limited?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because about terms of use, not coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want just a Geocoding API. You can easily do the calculations in your own code (there are multiple libs for it). Take a look at this [article that compare geocoding apis](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/7-free-geocoding-apis-google-bing-yahoo-and-mapquest/2012/06/21). Probably the one with the greatest limit is Yahoo. Ops, the free one has been deprecated!

Go with [Bing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701734.aspx), instead. It has a [limit of 30,000 queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213431/usage-limit-on-bing-geocoding-vs-google-geocoding)