# rewriting a for loop into to a -apply formular in R for georoute

Tags: r, lapply

I have a massive data.frame with the starting and ending (latitudes & longtitude) and am using the `georoute` function from the `taRifx.geo` package, to find out how far and how much time does it take to drive from A to B.

the data looked something like this (both `latlon` and `latlon_end` are class of `characters`:

```
> LL[1:10,14:15]
         latlon            latlon_end
1  52.481466 13.317647   52.518811 13.413034
2  52.518811 13.413034   52.504182 13.318051
3  52.504182 13.318051   52.502236 13.305396
4  52.502236 13.305396   52.548096 13.355104
5  52.548096 13.355104   52.569865 13.410967
6  52.569865 13.410967   52.54505 13.419071
7  52.54505 13.419071    52.527736 13.378182
8  52.527736 13.378182   52.495678 13.343019
9  52.495678 13.343019   52.496712 13.341767
10 52.496712 13.341767   52.458631 13.32529
```

and here is a `for` loop that I have written for the purpose:

```
for(i in 38753:100000){
  DT[i,]=tryCatch(t(as.matrix(unlist(georoute( c(as.character(LL$latlon[i]),
                                                  as.character(LL$latlon_end[i])),
                                                verbose=TRUE, returntype=c("time", "distance"))),
                               nrow = 1, ncol = 2)),
                   error=function(a) {"."} )
```

}

the base function here, `georoute` basically give out a list of two elements, `time` and `distance`, that's why I have to unlist them first before binding all them into a dataframe. for the `trycatch` function, that's to deal with occasional error for the `georoute`, I have no idea how alternatively I can do this..

I have really tried a lot of methods but only this seems to have to work out for me, since somehow **this `georoute` function seems to take only one pair of latlon & latlon_end at one time** so I have to do this row by row. However with a few hundred thousands of entries this is taking me days or even weeks to process all this data. I know I should go in the [package and understand the codes behind(link inserted)](https://github.com/gsk3/taRifx.geo/blob/master/R/Contributed.R) just so I know what is a better fit for this purpose, yet the script is too advanced for my level and I don't even know what in the script that I am looking for to be exact. I guess I could use the lapply function for this but I just can't make it work.

Any help or tips or ideas would be very really super greatly appreciated!

ps. update for original `georoute` returns

```
> georoute(c(as.character(LL$latlon[1]), as.character(LL$latlon_end[1])), verbose = FALSE, returntype = c("time","distance"))
  distance time
1     9.03 1338
> georoute(c(as.character(LL$latlon[1:3]), as.character(LL$latlon_end[1:3])), verbose = FALSE, returntype = c("time","distance"))
  distance time
1   35.599 5275
> class(georoute(c(as.character(LL$latlon[1]), as.character(LL$latlon_end[1])), verbose = FALSE, returntype = c("time","distance")))
[1] "data.frame"
```

and I think the `distance` and `time` returned are numeric because the summary of that shows the 4 quantiles, mean, medians etc.

Comment: I can't imagine the for loop being the bottleneck here. I'm not familiar with georoute but realistically it must take a long time to find a route between two points. A parallel version may be the only solution, if it is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider bypassing the package and use its data source, namely Bing's [Calculate a Route API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx) which interfaces to http://dev.virtualearth.net for json feeds per parameters. On closer read, the GitHub source code looks heavy with vector and matrix manipulation that proves heavy in processing. Simply a json feed needs to be parsed for *distance* and *time* data points.

Below uses the `jsonlite` library to send same parameters as package to build urls iteratively with each pair of Lat/Lon for waypoints. Once json feeds are imported, the needed dataframes are extracted into list. Do note: a Bing Maps API key is required which should have been per package requirements.

```
library(jsonlite)

BingMapsAPIkey <- "*****"

dfList <- lapply(seq(38753:100000), function(i) {

  url <- paste0("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes?wayPoint.1=", 
                gsub(" ", ",", LL$latlon[i]) , "&wayPoint.2=", gsub(" ", ",", LL$latlon_end[i]),
                "&maxSolutions=1&optimize=time&routePathOutput=Points&distanceUnit=km&travelMode=Driving",
                "&key=", BingMapsAPIkey)      
  tryCatch({
    jsondata <- fromJSON(url)
    return(jsondata$resourceSets$resources[[1]]$routeLegs[[1]]$routeSubLegs[[1]][c("travelDistance", "travelDuration")])
  }, error=function(e) return(data.frame(travelDistance=NA, travelDuration=NA)))

})

# ROW BIND DATAFRAME ELEMENTS IN LIST
geodf <- do.call(rbind, dfList)

# COLUMN BIND TO ORIGINAL DATAFRAME
df <- cbind(LL[38753:100000,], geodf)
```

**Output** *(using above posted Lat/Lon data)*

```
#                 latlon          latlon_end travelDistance travelDuration
# 1  52.481466 13.317647 52.518811 13.413034          9.030           1338
# 2  52.518811 13.413034 52.504182 13.318051          8.148           1269
# 3  52.504182 13.318051 52.502236 13.305396          1.694            254
# 4  52.502236 13.305396 52.548096 13.355104         11.700            820
# 5  52.548096 13.355104 52.569865 13.410967          5.966            919
# 6  52.569865 13.410967  52.54505 13.419071          3.110            576
# 7   52.54505 13.419071 52.527736 13.378182          3.851            728
# 8  52.527736 13.378182 52.495678 13.343019          6.196           1051
# 9  52.495678 13.343019 52.496712 13.341767          0.986            277
# 10 52.496712 13.341767  52.458631 13.32529          6.129            947
```

Comment: I just tried the codes but apparently the result is being pasted all into the same row. so I got the following message trying to process 5 rows: `Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, c("time", "distance"), value = list( :
  provided 10 variables to replace 2 variables`. Do you know any ways that can make R paste the result of each pair row by row?

Comment: that warning I got was for the `sapply` codes. When I try with `vapply` I got the same result pasted in all of the other rows.. any ideas :/ and thanks nethertheless! was so nice of you even went off to see the source code :(

Comment: Are you sure `georoute()` returns a list of two elements? Can you post the return value of a few of this function? From your `for` loop before your matrix conversion, print to screen the output of this method and edit in question.

Comment: See update that now uses only `lapply()` to retrieve a list of dataframes from the iterative `georoute()` calls. From there row bind dfs together then cbind into `LL`.

Comment: I experimented just the `lapply` part but seems that it's actually slower than the for loop, which is pretty weird

Comment: See update where we reverse engineer the Git package and go directly to data source to parse json feeds. You will need a Bing Maps API key.

Comment: I got all NAs for all columns and rows on my try.. just checked my API key still works tho

Comment: Are you sure data is structured exactly as you post at the position? Check: `LL[38753:100000, c("latlon", "latlon_end")]`. Also, I am [reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213431/usage-limit-on-bing-geocoding-vs-google-geocoding): *Bing limits you 30,000 transactions per day in the free developer account*. Check console -is there an *jsondata* object? Is *dfList* empty?

Comment: Yep the data is correctly positioned (though 38753:10000 was just the one part of the data and I am doing a bit further now, but I changed that in the `seq()` accordingly so that should be fine). _dfList_ returns a nice list just with all NAs as both distance and time. _jsondata_ was not found in the global env tho!

Comment: Error is being trapped by the `tryCatch()`. Outside of the loop, try building one url, replacing `i` with a number, like 1. Then call: `jsondata <- fromJSON(url)`. Even grab that URL and put in browser bar. See what message you receive.

Comment: I replaced all `i` in the loop and called but `jsondata` is still not there, so I just got error trying to get the url from JSON. What do you mean exactly by "try building one url outside the loop"?

Comment: Check if this URL works which uses first row's lat/lon pairs (be sure to API at end): `http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes?wayPoint.1=52.481466,13.317647&wayPoint.2=52.518811,13.413034&maxSolutions=1&optimize=time&routePathOutput=Points&distanceUnit=km&travelMode=Driving&key=BING_MAP_API_KEY`

Comment: yeh i got the message that my key wasn't accepted and checked that the api doesn't work anymore (it was still somehow working when i tried the `jsondata` thing). Then it's another problem. Don't really know how I can express how thankful I am though, you are truly a magician to me.